# Using java.util.collection data type as input parameter in PL/SQL

Tags: collections, plsql, jasper-reports, parameter-passing

I am going to write a procedure that should get an input parameter which its type is **Java.Util.Collection**. Indeed, I have a report in *Jaspersoft Studio* that is received a **Java.Util.Collection** parameter and generated report based on the parameter's data. Also, I want to write my queries in the database package and I do not know how to pass an input parameter of type **Java.Util.Collection** to the procedure of *PL/SQL*. 
Besides, I have declared a *type* in the package like this

`TYPE COLLECTION_TYPE IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(10);`

and use it as a parameter type in *procedure*, while an error is raised when I want to compile my package that said

`Error: PLS-00371: at most one declaration for 'COLLECTION_TYPE' is permitted`

Could you please guide me to solve this problem?
My *PL/SQL* code is like below code.
Thanks in advance.

`PROCEDURE procedure_name(I_ORGANIZATION IN COLLECTION_TYPE,
                                 O_CURSOR       OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) AS
  BEGIN
    OPEN O_CURSOR FOR
      SELECT TBL1.NAME
        FROM tbl_name TBL1
       WHERE TBL1.ORGANIZATIONID IN (I_ORGANIZATION);
  END;`

Comment: Can you show us how are you running query in some SQL editor ?

Answer (score 0):

In your code wrong is.

```
`WHERE TBL1.ORGANIZATIONID IN (I_ORGANIZATION);`
```

there is not such operation with collection type. 
replace it with `member_of` `TBL1.ORGANIZATIONID memeber_of I_ORGNAIZATION` or  `TBL1.ORGANIZATIONID in (select column_value from table(I_ORGANIZATION))`.

The error Error: PLS-00371. is generated in other place. 
You are using the same identifier name twice. Example.

```
declare 
 a varchar2(100);
 a number;
begin 
 a := 'aa';
end;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. In my _PL/SQL_ code, the command  
 _TBL1.ORGANIZATIONID in (select column_value from table(I_ORGANIZATION))_    works without any error. While, when I want to call this procedure from reports form _Jaspersoft Studio_ and pass a parameter that its data type is **java.util.collection** an error raises that say    _Invalid column type_.    Could you please guide me to solve this problem?